# R: How can I apply a condition on 3 columns so that calculation could be possible over a different column and the results are stored in a new df?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, bioinformatics

I'm wondering how I can calculate the mean from column 6 (`Mmet.diff`) when consecutive rows in columns 1, 2, and 3 (`chrom`, `start`, `end`  ) are identical.  In cases where the condition is met, the previously obtained values and the newly generated values would be kept in a separate dataframe. The identical rows from the first 3 columns would be collapsed into a single row.

The dataframe looks like this,

```
  print(TestDMR3sam, n=30)
# A tibble: 568 × 4
   chrom    start      end    Mmet.diff
   <chr>     <int>     <int>     <dbl>
 1 chr1    2017424   2017750    0.170 
 2 chr1    2019883   2020173    0.281 
 3 chr1    3899411   3899468   -0.316 
 4 chr1    4654862   4655147    0.158 
 5 chr1    4710490   4710875   -0.250 
 6 chr1    4710490   4710875   -0.233 
 7 chr1   16535549  16535834    0.293 
 8 chr1   24901325  24901700    0.163 
 9 chr1   24902268  24902701    0.105 
10 chr1   24927215  24927416    0.176 
11 chr1   24965375  24965581    0.224 
12 chr1   26861926  26862173    0.120 
13 chr1   26864186  26864613   -0.158 
14 chr1   35574331  35574705    0.119 
15 chr1   35576334  35576451   -0.301 
16 chr1   36304606  36304817   -0.238 
17 chr1   36305874  36305982    0.145 
18 chr1   37732310  37732512    0.185 
19 chr1   37766791  37766870   -0.185 
20 chr1   44632491  44632732    0.178 
21 chr1   44632877  44632946    0.0786
22 chr1   46506789  46506876    0.148 
23 chr1   47227823  47228049    0.209 
24 chr1   50103848  50103979    0.155 
25 chr1   67232241  67232364    0.119 
26 chr1   81801772  81802167    0.267 
27 chr1   90852089  90852325   -0.257 
28 chr1  109711736 109712104    0.428 
29 chr1  109712501 109712939    0.365 
30 chr1  109714072 109714219    0.133 
# ℹ 538 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Given that the 5th and 6th rows in this instance are identical, the expected result would be the mean of the 5th and 6th rows of the 4th column (-0.250-0.233)/2 = -0.2415, and the rows will be collapsed into the single row that is displayed below.
The expected output dataframe

```
chrom    start      end    Mmet.diff
   <chr>     <int>     <int>     <dbl>
 1 chr1    2017424   2017750    0.170 
 2 chr1    2019883   2020173    0.281 
 3 chr1    3899411   3899468   -0.316 
 4 chr1    4654862   4655147    0.158 
 6 chr1    4710490   4710875   -0.2415 
 7 chr1   16535549  16535834    0.293 
 8 chr1   24901325  24901700    0.163 
 9 chr1   24902268  24902701    0.105 
10 chr1   24927215  24927416    0.176 
11 chr1   24965375  24965581    0.224 
12 chr1   26861926  26862173    0.120 
13 chr1   26864186  26864613   -0.158 
14 chr1   35574331  35574705    0.119 
15 chr1   35576334  35576451   -0.301 
16 chr1   36304606  36304817   -0.238 
17 chr1   36305874  36305982    0.145 
18 chr1   37732310  37732512    0.185 
19 chr1   37766791  37766870   -0.185 
20 chr1   44632491  44632732    0.178 
21 chr1   44632877  44632946    0.0786
22 chr1   46506789  46506876    0.148 
23 chr1   47227823  47228049    0.209 
24 chr1   50103848  50103979    0.155 
25 chr1   67232241  67232364    0.119 
26 chr1   81801772  81802167    0.267 
27 chr1   90852089  90852325   -0.257 
28 chr1  109711736 109712104    0.428 
29 chr1  109712501 109712939    0.365 
30 chr1  109714072 109714219    0.133
```

Comment: I think this is essentially: [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group) - please let me know if the answers over there are not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Great, Thanks.
`TestDMR3samCons<-TestDMR3sam %>% 
  group_by(chrom,start,end) %>% 
  summarise(across(Mmet.diff, mean, na.rm = TRUE))`